# FileNotFoundError: No such file: 'someones_epi.nii.gzip'

Tags: image, python-3.x, medical

I am trying to load an MRI, I keep getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "F:/Study/Projects/BTSaG/Programs/t3.py", line 2, in <module> epi_img = nib.load('someones_epi.nii.gzip') 
File "C:\Users\AnkitaShinde\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\nibabel\loadsave.py", line 38, in load raise FileNotFoundError("No such file: '%s'" % filename) 
FileNotFoundError: No such file: 'someones_epi.nii.gzip'
```

The code is used is as follows:

```
import nibabel as nib
epi_img = nib.load('someones_epi.nii.gzip')
epi_img_data = epi_img.get_data()
epi_img_data.shape(53, 61, 33)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def show_slices(slices):
""" Function to display row of image slices """
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, len(slices))
for i, slice in enumerate(slices):
     axes[i].imshow(slice.T, cmap="gray", origin="lower")
slice_0 = epi_img_data[26, :, :]
slice_1 = epi_img_data[:, 30, :]
slice_2 = epi_img_data[:, :, 16]
show_slices([slice_0, slice_1, slice_2])
plt.suptitle("Center slices for EPI image")
```

I have also updated the loadsave.py file in nibabel but it didn't work. Please help.

*Edit:*
The earlier error was resolved. Now another error has been encountered.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):File "F:\Study\Projects\BTSaG\Programs\t3.py", line 2, in <module> epi_img = nib.load('someones_epi.nii.gzip')
File "C:\Users\AnkitaShinde\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\nibabel\loadsave.py", line 47, in load filename)
nibabel.filebasedimages.ImageFileError: Cannot work out file type of "someones_epi.nii.gzip"
```

Comment: post some info about dir structure so we know where the file is really located.

Comment: C:\Users\AnkitaShinde\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages\nibabel\someones_epi.nii.gzip

Comment: so why there? `load` needs path relative to actually executed script or absolute path.so in Your case you should putit in `F:/Study/Projects/BTSaG/Programs/`

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, however I may have the solution for it.

I just figured out that nibabel.save() does not allow me to have dot `.` or dash `-` in the folder names. These can exist in filenames however. In your case, the current path is:

`C:\Users\AnkitaShinde\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages\nibabel\someones_epi.nii.gzip`

I would change it to:

`C:\Users\AnkitaShinde\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35_32\Lib\site_packages\nibabel\someones_epi.nii.gzip`

This is just to give an example. Of course, I don't mean that you actually change the names of these package folders as it might cause other errors.

The actual solution would be to move the file someones_epi.nii.gzip to the user structure, something like:

`C:\Users\AnkitaShinde\Desktop\nibabel\someones_epi.nii.gzip`